Can we know for certain that "go on" only means "continue" in "The graduation ceremony will go on, regardless of weather."?
Farlex's dictionary of idioms has this definition of the phrasal verb go on:


verb To proceed or persist.

"The graduation ceremony will go on, regardless of weather."

The words proceed & persist indicate that it's the continue sense that's meant here. But there is another sense of go on, begin:


To begin. Used especially of performances or broadcasts: The show goes on at 6:00. The show first went on the air in 1972.
(The American
Heritage® Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs. Copyright © 2005)


Can we know for certain that go on means only continue, in the sentence "The graduation ceremony will go on, regardless of weather." or could it also mean begin?

A synonymous phrase would be "happen/occur as planned".  That other sense (12) would only apply to a ceremony if it were being broadcast and the reference was to the broadcast.  It would be "comes on" if from the perspective of the audience. "goes on" is from the perspective of those presenting it.

on in meaning 12 refers to the content of the broadcast being at this moment audible and/or visible on the particular medium.  "Quiet! The show's on."  The radio broadcast, television show, or movie has begun, so stop talking.  We say  "a radio show" even though you cannot see it.

Whether go on means continue or begin will be right there in context. Go on to mean perform likely shortens go onstage.

Without knowing the full context I would expect "go on" in this context to be something like "will occur" rather than "continue". In this case I would expect whatever the anticipated circumstance is, it occurs before the ceremony starts rather than in the middle of it. But that is fairly weak due to not having a full description.

Note that besides meaning continue (of a thing already begun) proceed can also mean take place as planned.

@Paul Tanenbaum And is this the meaning here? I can't find a single definition in any dictionary that would convey "take place as planned" meaning.

Yes, here go on does mean take place as planned. Compare it to the cliché, “The show must go on,” which dictum could be invoked (1) if a star became injured or ill in the midst of a performance already under way or (2) if the star became thus unavailable even before the performance had begun.

This seems to be an extension of the idiom "The show must go on", a saying in the theatre that the show must be performed, no matter what happens before or during.  The show must both begin (as planned) and continue (as planned).
So in terms of your dictionary definitions, both senses apply.  The graduation ceremony will begin and continue until its finish. But the particular choice of words is influence by the idiom.

I was thinking about the same thing. I even researched it and I read that it means that the show must "begin". This is actually the main reason I wrote this post (Aside form not knowing for sure). So basically, the answer is no, as I expected. You can't say, definitely, if  "go on" in "The graduation ceremony will go on, regardless of weather." means "begin" or "continue" without more context.

You can definitely say that it means both "begin" and (having begun) "continue".

Ok, thank you for your answer.
